# Fedora Chrome, can't access localhost or 127.0.0.1 when offline

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, fedora

I have my local httpd or Apache open. It works when online, but not when offline... How can I make it work?

Comment: How are you going offline? Offline in browsers usually means "everything".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Google Chrome. Starting Chrome with --enable-ipv6 fixes it.

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058 for details.

Comment: wow , it works!! That time searched for sooo long d , haha , thx

Comment: BTW it looks like it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 should work regardless of what's in /etc/hosts

If you do an `ifconfig` do you see the `lo` loopback interface?

This may be a better question for superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, when offline you can use the `ifconfig` command manually to configure the Ethernet card. For example, set `eth0` to an IP address. Then you can access localhost.

For example:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.101
```

Answer (score 0):

Has it anything to do with the `etc/hosts` file?  Do you have `localhost` defined in there?

If not, your machine may be using DNS to resolve localhost, where if it is set in the host file, you should be able to access it while offline.

Comment: # hostname localhost.localdomain added to /etc/hosts by anaconda
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6 localhost.localdomain

i think this means that i have set it already , right?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for. Every time you log in to Fedora you have to start Apache
Therefore you need to execute the following commands

```
sudo service httpd start
```

You may also run into problems in the future if you need to use phpmyadmin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9POEy.png)

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server
>
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Remember to use the following command after installing phpmyadmin after each login

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```